# CoreData query to retrieve most recent item from each of many groups

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm working with CoreData in Xcode 9.4.1 + Swift 4.1.2 on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6, targeting iOS. In my data model, I have entities which have fields F1 and F2. Both fields are timestamps.

For each value of F1, there can be multiple values of F2. I'd like to retrieve from CoreData the items which have the most recent value of F2, among the items which have the same value of F1. So the result should have one item per distinct value of F1, and that item will have the greatest value of F2, among all items which have that same value of F1. What is the appropriate request predicate for that?

Just to be clear, I'm hoping to get CoreData to do the grouping and filtering for me; at present I'm doing some work in my own code, but I'd like to let CoreData take over.

I've tried to determine the answer by reviewing the documentation for NSPredicate and looking up answers on SO, but I've come up empty-handed. Thanks in advance for any light you can shed.

Comment: You'll need to set F1 as the `propertiesToGroupBy` for the fetchRequest, and to use `NSExpression` and `NSExpressionDescription` to get the maximum value of F2 as a `propertiesToFetch`.  If you search on those keywords you should find something useful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's very helpful. I remember now that there is an additional constraint I need to impose. The value of F2 to be chosen is not just the maximum, but the greatest value less than or equal to a specified threshold. Is that scenario also feasible via propertiesToFetch?

Comment: Seems like the comment posted by @pbasbdf should be an answer.  Anyhow, after you get this working, it would be real interesting to A/B test and see if this performs better than your existing code.  Maybe so, but not necessarily!

Comment: @RobertDodier You should be able just to specify your constraint (“F2 <= threshold”) as a predicate for the fetch.  The objects will be filtered first, then grouped by F1, then the maximum value of F2 will be found for each group.

Comment: @pbasdf Thanks a lot, I will give it a try.